# PhpStorm shows button which jumps to function

Tags: user-interface, phpstorm, settings

Does anyone knows how to remove this button?

When I hover it shows "Function". Clicking right selects the method the cursor is located at.

I already disabled all plugins but still showing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | General | Appearance`
3. Uncheck `Show breadcrumbs` option

NOTE: It will remove it for all supported languages (e.g. HTML/XML/CSS/etc) and not just PHP.